# Lorentz force expression and its implications

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I found this information about Lorentz force in my textbook (as an extra point):

But I couldn't understand the meaning of the last statement: "Lorentz force expression does not imply a universal preferred frame of reference in nature."
Can someone please elaborate on it.

[image]

Comment: This means that if in an inertial frame $\:\rm S\:$ the Lorentz force 3-vector is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf F= q\left(\mathbf E +\mathbf v\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf B\right)
\tag{01}\label{01}
\end{equation}
then in any other inertial frame $\:\rm S'\:$ in uniform translational motion with respect to $\:\rm S\:$ the Lorentz force 3-vector is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf F'= q\left(\mathbf E' +\mathbf v'\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf B'\right)
\tag{02}\label{02}
\end{equation} But be careful. The primed vectors are related with the unprimed via the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Related : [Are magnetic fields just modified relativistic electric fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411070/are-magnetic-fields-just-modified-relativistic-electric-fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean that the appearance of ${\bf v}$ in the formula
$$
{\bf F}= q({\bf E}+{\bf v}\times {\bf B})
$$
appears to require that the velocity of the charged particle has to be measured with respect to specific  "rest frame." This is not the case. If you are in a frame moving with velocity ${\bf V}$ then, to you,  the charged particle moves with velocity ${\bf v}-{\bf V}$ and

$$
{\bf F}=q({\bf E}'+ ({\bf v}-{\bf V})\times {\bf B}).
$$

This is the same force ${\bf F}$ but ${\bf E}'={\bf E}+{\bf V}\times{\bf B} $, so the electric field has changed in your new frame.

Comment: Mike, your answer is relativitically totally wrong. Especially as concerns to the velocity and the electromagnetic field in the new frame. Related : [Are magnetic fields just modified relativistic electric fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411070/are-magnetic-fields-just-modified-relativistic-electric-fields).

Comment: @Frobenius.  Of course!. I am just using the Galilean limit.  I doubt that the OP has got of the point of studying SR, and the book is using Galilean language.

Comment: Ok, Mike, accepted.